# cloudflare_worker_script multiple files

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers, cloudflare-pages, cloudflare-apps, terraform-provider-cloudflare

Using CloudFlare web dashboard it's possible to split your code into multiple files using ES module syntax. It works out of the box.

[image]

Is it possible to create such configuration using CF Terraform provider and `cloudflare_worker_script` without JS bundles like webpack?

```
resource "cloudflare_worker_script" "spainter_script_file_utils" {
  name = "spainter"
  account_id = var.cloud_flare_account_id
  content = file("./workers.js")
  module = true
}
```

According to their [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cloudflare/cloudflare/latest/docs/resources/worker_script) there's no such option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not - [the API](https://developers.cloudflare.com/api/operations/worker-script-upload-worker-module) supports uploading other JavaScript files as additional modules but the Terraform provider hasn't implemented that so it expects you to bundle yourself using Webpack, esbuild, etc